# How to convert a @ToString generated string back to object with Groovy

Tags: groovy, instantiation, object-construction

For example, instance of the following following class produces string `A(x:7, values:[hello, world])`

```
@ToString( includeNames=true )
class A {
    def x
    def values = []
}
```

How can I transform this String back to an instance of the class?

Comment: you would have to parse it and this is extremly error prone (set `values=['hello, world']` and see it fall apart).

Comment: @dmahapatro At the moment that's how some results are written on the log. Loggin in JSON format is on the way, but I need to do some analysis based on the earlier results. As the software is written with Groovy I thought I could skip some regexp parsing.

Comment: if the output would have been generated with `inspect()` you could use `Eval` (with all the pain, that would bring)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the comments by @cfrick, this is not possible.

(Answering my own question for the sake of closing this topic.)